# Is there a working Desktop Authenticator App for MFA? (with no mobile device involved)

Tags: security, authentication, login, mfa

I have very mixed feelings towards the enforcement of MFA by Salesforce, which as a consequence enforces the usage of authenticator apps. I have over 400 developer orgs to deal with. I have to login on dozens of orgs every day.

Right now, I'm using email verification. I can do everything on desktop in one smooth clicking sequence with drag&drop of the code from my email.

With a authenticator app on a phone, this process would involve my phone and even worse: the annoying manual typing of the code. With my bare fingers! Error prone and disruptive. This sucks.

Doing it one single time is just a little distraction. But doing it many times a day it hurts. I have to use several different browsers and several different computers and different devices to login. So I really have to re-authenticate many many times a day.

Currently we are using the Google Authenticator app on the phone. Is there a viable 100%-desktop-focused and mobile-FREE method to login and authenticate in the upcoming MFA era?

We have already tried some desktop apps but they did not work well. We are looking for something other people have used already successfully to avoid a huge waste of time to test them all.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Sounds like a perfect fit for [Environment Hub](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Environment_Hub). If you can't do that, then inbound SSO with MFA at the identity provider would be our 2nd recommendation.

Comment: Have you tried Lightning Login?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: Twilio is removing [Authy for Desktop](https://help.twilio.com/articles/22771146070299-User-guide-End-of-Life-EOL-for-Twilio-Authy-Desktop-app) March 19, 2024**

I've had no issues with [Authy](https://authy.com/download/) desktop (on a Windows 10 PC).

You can add the salesforce account directly through the desktop app and get the token as well.

I have it on my phone as well and I believe this is required (as it's connected to your phone number).

Adding tokens/sites syncs across all your devices (Tablet, Phone, Desktop).

[image]

---

It might also be worth testing out whether the [trusted location in Salesforce Authenticator](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_authenticator_trust_location_and_automate.htm&type=5) will help if you're working from the same location and not using VPN. This would eliminate your pain of having to look at your phone or manually copy the code as it would auto-verify you.

Answer (score 2):

With 400 orgs that you potentially need to access, I assume you're using a password manager of some sort? As far as I know the market-leaders generally have MFA capabilities built in. Certainly using 1Password, I can log in to an org with a keyboard shortcut, and it automatically loads the current 2FA token into my clipboard. This is something we've had in general use for years, with widespread adoption of 2FA.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommened [Authy](https://authy.com/download/) by Twilio.

I migrated from Microsoft Authenticator to Authy a few months back and they've fit my needs (multiple orgs, desktop-first) perfectly. Free of cost, No-ads and no 'premium' subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

My company is also using 1Password.  We log into multiple orgs each day and so far, I'm a big fan.  Within 1Password, there's an option to Open and Fill, so everything is populated for you.  Good luck!

Comment: 1Password requires additional steps to meet MFA requirements: https://support.1password.com/one-time-passwords/